# Calculate division between outputs of 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to calculate the scrap rate. So that my output will give something like.

```
Scrap Product Total Count 
-------------------
Product Total Count
```

I have two tables:

```
Product
--------
Barcode 1
Barcode 2 
Barcode 3
Barcode 4
```

### Scrap Product

```
Barcode 2
Barcode 4
```

I have been trying different queries using pivot operators, and query below.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

```
select (
select count(barcode)
FROM ScrapProduct)
 / 
(
select count(barcode)
FROM Product) as total_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically fine.  But you'll have an issue with integer division.  So, you need decimals in your numbers.  I find this the simplest method:

```
select ( (select count(barcode) from ScrapProduct) * 1.0 / 
         (select count(barcode) from Product)
       ) as scrap_rate
```

If you want three columns, then move the subqueries to the `from` clause:

```
select num_scrap, num_product, (num_scrap  * 1.0 / num_product) as scrap_rate 
from (select count(barcode) as num_scrap from ScrapProduct) sp cross join
      (select count(barcode) as num_product from Product) p
```